# Emacs + ESS with Anaconda in cluster?

Tags: ess, r

i want to run a different version of R when I start ESS (Emacs Speaks Statistics). It is on a grid environment and using anaconda, so I would like it to run the following scripts.

conda activate myenv
R --grid_mem=50g

(the R command is a shell wrapper)

But I still want all the ESS functionality for R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use-case, I think [ess-remote](https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS_002dremote) may be the best option.

1. Start a new shell in Emacs (i.e., `M-x shell`)
2. ssh in to your cluster and start the R program (`conda activate myenv R --grid_mem=50g`)
3. Call `M-x ess-remote` and follow the prompts to connect ESS to the remote process.

See the linked help page for more details and options.

Comment: thank you so much!